# счетчик страниц сдайдера swiper

Tags: javascript, swiper

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить мой код, чтобы он считал не количество слайдов, а количество страниц со слайдами. Буду благодарен любому ответу.

```js
//инициализация слайдера
const swiper__products = new Swiper('.choice__slider', {

slidesPerView: 1,
slidesPerGroup: 1,
spaceBetween: 72,

pagination: {
    el: '.aside__progressbar',

    type: 'progressbar'
},

breakpoints: {

    767: {
        slidesPerView: 2,
        slidesPerGroup: 2,
    },
    1200: {
        slidesPerView: 3,
        slidesPerGroup: 3,
    },
}    });



//добавляем 0 перед цифрой
function formatFraction (number) {
    if (number < 10) {
        number = '0' + number;
    }
    return number;
};

// код счетчика слайдов
let mySliderAllSlides = document.querySelector('.aside__total')
let mySliderCurrentSlide = document.querySelector('.aside__current');

mySliderAllSlides.innerHTML = formatFraction(swiper__products.slides.length);

swiper__products.on('slideChange', function() {
    let currentSlide = formatFraction(swiper__products.realIndex + 1);
    mySliderCurrentSlide.innerHTML = currentSlide;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.css"
/>

<div class="choice__slider">

  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="aside__counter">
      <div class="aside__current">01</div>
      <div class="aside__total">05</div>
  </div>
  <div class="aside__progressbar"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

В [документации](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api) есть описание

Используем событие `init` - после инициализации слайдов получаем индекс (в данном случае при выключенном loop можно вместо `realIndex` использовать `index`) делим на количество слайдов на экране и получаем индексы 0,1,2... добавляем единицу чтоб индекс начинался с 1 а не 0

Тоже самое делаем и для события `slideChange` (событие при смене слайдов)

```js
var slidesPerView = 3
var $counter = document.querySelector(".counter")
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
  slidesPerView: slidesPerView,
  spaceBetween: 30,
  slidesPerGroup: slidesPerView,
  loopFillGroupWithBlank: true,
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    clickable: true,
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },
  on: {
    init: function(){
      $counter.innerHTML = this.realIndex / slidesPerView + 1
    },
    slideChange: function(){
      $counter.innerHTML = this.realIndex / slidesPerView + 1
    }
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.counter {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: red;
  z-index: 100000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Swiper demo</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
  <!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Swiper -->
  <div class="swiper mySwiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="counter"></div>
  <!-- Swiper JS -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: в таком случае мы крепко привязаны к var slidesPerView = 3, а если на адаптиве изменяется количество слайдов для показа/прокрутки, то как быть?

Comment: Все в той же документации. Слушать событие [breakpoint](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#event-breakpoint) и делить не на переменную `slidesPerView` а менять переменную свою и  вывести в функцию изменения числа и делить на количество слайдов (ту самую свою переменную). Учтите что если количество слайдов кратно трем но не кратно двум, то нужно будет немного просчеты корректировать так как будет остаток от деления, но если использовать 6, 12, 18 слайдов то не нужно

Comment: Я попробовал в сниппете добавить событие `breakpoint: function(swiper, breakpointParams){console.log(breakpointParams}` и сниппет то работает  и вызывает событие `breakpoint` то вообще не перестраивается (соответственно и событие не вызывается) попробуйте на локальном компьютере, `breakpointParams` должен вернуть объект `{slidesPerView: число, slidesPerGroup: число}`, или что то подобное